# How can I set variable in other namespace equal to variable in procedure?

Tags: tcl

I have TCL code:

```
namespace eval gen {
    proc generate { } {
        set language "C"
        namespace eval current_file_generation_info {
            variable language $language
        }
    }
}
```

At line `variable language $language` I am trying to set variable `language` in namespace `current_file_generation_info` to the value of variable `language` inside procedure `generate`. My code gives me error something like "language variable does not exists" and I understand why it does so.

So my question is, how can I set the variable `language` in namespace `current_file_generation_info` equal to variable `language` inside `generate` procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to just name the target namespace in the `variable` call, but if you do that, you should make the namespace as a separate step (if it is possible to call the code at a point when the NS wasn't already created).

```
namespace eval gen {
    proc generate { } {
        # Make the namespace by running an empty script in it
        namespace eval current_file_generation_info {}
        # Initialise the variable
        variable current_file_generation_info::language "C"
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you could do:

```
namespace eval gen {
    proc generate { } {
        namespace eval current_file_generation_info \
                [list variable language "C"]
    }
}
```

Hint: the `list` command is very good at generating substitution-free scripts that call a single command.

Comment: Which is the best way to use `current_file_generation_info::language` variable from other namespace?

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace eval gen {
    proc generate { } {
        set language "C"
        set [namespace current]::language $language
    }
    generate
    variable language
    puts $language
}
```

It would be clearer to avoid using the same variable name for a local var and a namespace var

```
namespace eval gen {
    proc generate { } {
        variable language
        set _language "C"
        set language $_language
    }
}
```

or just omit the local var

```
namespace eval gen {
    proc generate { } {
        variable language
        set language "C"
    }
}
```

Comment: In your example the `language` variable is created in `gen` namespace in the procedure that is in `gen` namespace. I need to create variable `language` in the `current_file_generation_info` namespace form procedure that is in `gen` namespace.